# angularjs input value binding and validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dynamic `regExp` and dynamic masks for each input. For example: regExp is `[0-9]{9,9}` and mask is `XXX-XX-XX-XX`. Of course for angular's pattern validation it is incorrect.

Is it possible, that angular somehow deem this value correct? For example: `222-22-22-22`

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Create custom directive to convert mask to regexp and apply `ngPattern`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly , you can use [ui-mask](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask) for this .

```
<input id='ui-mask' name="date" ng-model="date" required autocomplete='off' ui-mask='"99-99-9999"'>
```

This would mask the input as the given pattern of number. Here is a [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mchung/TaFw7/3/) . Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML5, you can use the "pattern" attribute for input and let the browser do the rest. Obviously, with AngularJS, you can let this attribute to be dynamic. Look at the code above:

```
<input type="text" pattern="{{mc.pattern}}" ng-model="mc.model">
```

If the user inputs an invalid text then the input (and form) will be not valid.

Let me know if I can help you better.

Bye